# res.end not stopping script from executing

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm currently trying to build an API around a 3rd party API however in my Express route I can't seem to get the current script to stop executing, here's my code:

```
app.get('/submit/:imei', async function (req, res) {
    //configure
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    MyUserAgent = UserAgent.getRandom();
    axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;

    const model_info = await getModelInfo(req.params.imei).catch(function (error) {
        if(error.response && error.response.status === 406) {
            return res.send(JSON.stringify({
                'success': false,
                'reason': 'exceeded_daily_attempts'
            }));
        }
    });


    console.log('This still gets called even after 406 error!');
});
```

How can I stop the script from executing if a **406** error is returned from the initial request?

Comment: Are you sure that it's hitting the `catch` or even going inside that conditional? There's no success case even being considered here, so it might just be working but not returning anything.

Comment: @MinusFour I'd assume so as my browser is being shown the JSON response

Comment: So, what do you mean by "stopping" the script. It hits the `console.log` line because you caught the error.

Comment: @MinusFour I don't want it to be continuing the script if the API returns a 406 response from which I'm trying to gather data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want code to execute after catching the error then you should do:

```
app.get('/submit/:imei', async function (req, res) {
    //configure
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    MyUserAgent = UserAgent.getRandom();
    axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
    try {
        const model_info = await getModelInfo(req.params.imei);    
        console.log('This will not get called if there is an error in getModelInfo');
        res.send({ success: true });
    } catch(error) {
        if(error.response && error.response.status === 406) {
            return res.send({
                'success': false,
                'reason': 'exceeded_daily_attempts'
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Alternatively you can use `then` after the `getModelInfo` call and that code will only be called if `getModelInfo` does not reject.

Answer (score 0):

It should have a success block too.

```js
app.get('/submit/:imei', async function (req, res) {
    //configure
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    MyUserAgent = UserAgent.getRandom();
    axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;

    const model_info = await getModelInfo(req.params.imei)
        .then(function (response) {
            return res.send(JSON.stringify({
                'success': true,
                'res': response
            }));

        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            if (error.response && error.response.status === 406) {
                return res.send(JSON.stringify({
                    'success': false,
                    'reason': 'exceeded_daily_attempts'
                }));
            }
        });

    //it will console log
    console.log('This still gets called even after 406 error!');
});
```